Help with coding a link for a button in WordPress with The Events Calendar Plugin
This is my first time asking a question on Stack Exchange.  Sorry if I don't do it right.  I'm using WordPress on a client redesign.  They sell courses on their site using the Events Calendar plugin.  Their previous website had an enrollment button that linked to an enrollment form on another page.  When you click the button it pulls information from the current course and pricing info and automatically filled it in on the enrollment form.  Here's the button link on the old site:  https://energeticentry.com/course-enrollment/?teesEventName=Hostage+Rescue+%2F+High+Risk+Warrant+Course+%26%238211%3B+Ennis%2C+TX&teesEventPrice=$1000&teesEventLoc=&teesEventDate=May%2021
I can't figure out how to do that on the new website.  I've looked through developer documentation on the plugin developer site, looked through all website files and I cannot locate the button or code.
I don't know what to replace in this URL to give me the info I need for the new site.  They were not using the Events Ticket plugin on the old site.  Thanks for any help.
I got it working now.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Basically all of these items in the URL are parameters that the receiving page uses to pre-fill the form.  ?teesEventName=Hostage+Rescue+%2F+High+Risk+Warrant+Course+%26%238211%3B+Ennis%2C+TX&teesEventPrice=$1000&teesEventLoc=&teesEventDate=May%2021 We'd need to see your form code to help you parse the parameters into fillable fields.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I did figure most of it out, but for some reason the button isn't clickable directly.  If I right-click and select open in new tab, then it does what it's supposed to do.  This is the url of the enrollment form after opened in new tab - https://michellee100.sg-host.com/course-enrollment/?teesEventName=SOLD%20OUT%20Explosive%20Handlers%20%26%23038%3B%20Breaching%20Course%20%26%238211%3B%20Cambridge%2C%20OH&teesEventPrice=%241575.00.                   This is the url where button is located:  https://michellee100.sg-host.com/event/explosive-handlers-breaching-course-cambridge-oh/

It's working now.  Thank you so much for your help!

They are using a gravity form for the old website.
Gravity forms has a feature where the 'event name' and other values can be passed to the form to create the details for the event billing.
Using Event Tickets will be very different. In this case each Calendar Entry will need the ticket item setup in the backend of WordPress.
You won't be able to do the same thing as before.
You also won't get support from The Event Calendar team for this kind of customisation.
